# email sending issue

Tags: java, spring

I am getting error while sending email with attached file. If i provide static path then email sending working perfectly file. but while i send file with below code is not working.

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    Map<String,MultipartFile> filess = multipartRequest.getFileMap();
    if(filess.size()>0){
        for(MultipartFile ff : filess.values()){
            System.out.println(ff.getOriginalFilename());
            file = new File(ff.getOriginalFilename()); 

        }
```

email sending class throws FileNotFoundException while passing file object. Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: what it has to do with ExtJs?

Comment: just pickup filefield form ExtJS and handle it on java side. That's it

Answer (score 0):

ff.getOriginalFilename() just returns the name of the file that the client specified in the request, it doesn't give you a full path to the file that has been uploaded to the server. You'll need to use ff.getInputStream() or ff.getBytes().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used transferTo(filee); and it's working